# I want to change a column type to date in R from csv file

Tags: r, csv, date

I can't figure out how to instruct R to change the columns "created_at" and "deadline" into date format. I don't recognize a date/time pattern in the numbers.

[image]

Comment: Please don't upload code, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: We also don't know what `kicstart` looks like, so it's difficult to help you. Please see here for how to ask a good R question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @Limey I will keep that in mind for future posts. Thanks

Comment: Hello @AndreaM the variables "created_at" and "deadline" should be dates. If it helps, this dataset is supposed to represent data gathered in 02-2022. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the numbers represent seconds from some origin (perhaps 1970-01-01 00:00:00), you can use `as.POSIXct()`:

```r
as.POSIXct(1240456019, origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00")
# [1] "2009-04-22 23:06:59 EDT"
as.POSIXct(1242467940, origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00")
# [1] "2009-05-16 05:59:00 EDT"
```

To do this to the entire variable, do:

```r
kickstart$created_at = as.POSIXct(kickstart$created_at, origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00")
kickstart$deadline = as.POSIXct(kickstart$deadline, origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00")
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion with different origin dates 1982 and 1975. Surprisingly I get the same dates for both origin dates which is puzzling.

Comment: 'head(kickstart$created_at)'
1370358703 1363533018
'kickstart$created_at = as.POSIXct(kickstart$created_at, origin = "1982-01-01 00:00:00")'
'head(kickstart$created_at)'
"2025-06-04 15:11:43 UTC" "2025-03-17 15:10:18 UTC"
'kickstart$created_at = as.POSIXct(kickstart$created_at, origin = "1975-01-01 00:00:00")'
'head(kickstart$created_at)'
"2025-06-04 15:11:43 UTC" "2025-03-17 15:10:18 UTC"

Comment: I get two different results: `x <- c(1370358703, 1363533018)`, then ` as.POSIXct(x, origin = "1982-01-01 00:00:00")` gives me `"2025-06-04 11:11:43 EDT" "2025-03-17 11:10:18 EDT"` and `as.POSIXct(x, origin = "1975-01-01 00:00:00")` gives me `"2018-06-04 11:11:43 EDT" "2018-03-17 11:10:18 EDT"`